# angularjs directive 'dataSource' And =

Tags: angularjs

This is really weird.

Does not work

```
scope: { 'dataSource': '='}
```

Works

```
scope: { 'mySource': '='}
```

Works

```
scope: { 'data': '='}
```

Can anyone tell me why in the 1st fiddle console.log prints undefined, and in the second 99.

http://jsfiddle.net/xz261bam/

http://jsfiddle.net/mg9axkro/

Comment: its because of the keyword 'data'. 'xdataSource' would work just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you will smack yourself on the head for this one... :)

The "data-" html5 prefix is stripped off, what you really get in your linking "source" not "dataSource":

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('myElement', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {            
            'source': '=',            
        },
        template: '<p>test</p>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            console.log(scope.source);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the "stripped off" and the actual linking evaluation :)

Answer (score 2):

There is obviously a conflict with HTML [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) if your name uses the data-whatever prefix. xdata-whatever or x-data-whatever is working just fine

```
<my-element xdata-source="counter"></my-element
```

or

```
<my-element x-data-source="counter"></my-element
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/x78376sx/)

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said, the `data-` prefix is stripped off, and change the scope's property name will solve the problem.

An alternative way is to double the `data-` prefix like this:

```
<my-element data-data-source="counter"></my-element>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4j3sks6u/